# JPA Criteria Query API and order by two columns

Tags: java, jpa, sql-order-by, criteria-api

I'm stuck with a simple problem; struggling how to invoke `order by` on a `join`ed entity. Essentially I am trying to achieve the following with `JPA Criteria`:

```
select distinct d from Department d 
left join fetch d.children c 
left join fetch c.appointments a
where d.parent is null 
order by d.name, c.name
```

I have the following:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Department> c = cb.createQuery(Department.class);
Root<Department> root = c.from(Department.class);
Fetch<Department, Department> childrenFetch = root.fetch(
    Department_.children, JoinType.LEFT);
childrenFetch.fetch(Department_.appointments, JoinType.LEFT);

c.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(Department_.name)));
c.distinct(true);
c.select(root);
c.where(cb.isNull(root.get(Department_.parent)));
```

How to achieve `order by d.name, c.name` with `Criteria API`? I tried with Expression, Path but didn't work.
Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 100):

If you need to add couple of orders you can make something like (but for your query and different root objects)

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Route> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Route.class);
Root<Route> routeRoot = query.from(Route.class);
query.select(routeRoot);

List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList();
query.where(routeRoot.get("owner").in(user));

orderList.add(criteriaBuilder.desc(routeRoot.get("date")));
orderList.add(criteriaBuilder.desc(routeRoot.get("rating")));

query.orderBy(orderList);
```

Answer (score 20):

I have the same problem with order by  using Criteria API. I found this solution:

```
CriteriaQuery<Test> q = cb.createQuery(Test.class);
Root<Test> c = q.from(Test.class);
q.select(c);
q.orderBy(cb.asc(c.get("name")), cb.desc(c.get("prenom")));
```

Answer (score 9):

I was having trouble doing the same, and I have found a solution on this page:
http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/criteria/CriteriaQuery/orderBy_Order_

```
//javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery
//CriteriaQuery<T> orderBy(Order... o)
```

> Specify the ordering expressions that are used to order the query results. Replaces the previous ordering expressions, if any. If no ordering expressions are specified, the previous ordering, if any, is simply removed, and results will be returned in no particular order. The left-to-right sequence of the ordering expressions determines the precedence, whereby the leftmost has highest precedence.
>
> Parameters:
>      o - zero or more ordering expressions
>
> Returns:
>      the modified query
>
> Since:
>      JPA 2.0

Comment: How is this an answer for problem author described?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't? He wanted to know, how to order by multiple properties. My answer contains how to do that... Am I missing something?

Comment: Because it will not work with distinct and sorting by property from join table

Answer (score 0):

`categoryRepository.findAll(predicates, new Sort(Direction.ASC, "sortOrder", "name"))
                    .forEach(categoryDtoList::add);`

Comment: this can be used to order a list based on both sortOrder and name
if the sortOrder is same based on the name it will sort the elements

Comment: This is only for Spring Data users.

Answer (score 0):

The solucion that work for me is the following

```
session=HibernateUtil.getSessionJavaConfigFactory_report().openSession();
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);
List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList();
orderList.add(builder.desc(ejeRoot.get("name")));
criteriaQuery.orderBy(orderList);
```

Note: ejeRoot is the class object